# Compare two products big data set

Tags: python, machine-learning, sphinx

I have two different product data of 5.4 Million and 4.5 Million Products, which **scraped** from the competitor website. Most products are non branded products that don't have any unique standard SKU. I want to compare 300K product data with similar products which our competitor are selling and want to find out the price difference.

I have tired compare dataset using two different sphinx with similar words but not able to find out a good result because of the title are not similar of non branded products with a standard brand name, title or SKU

Is there any way to get the result using ML or some big data algorithm ?

Comment: The only thing that springs to mind is https://github.com/dedupeio/csvdedupe ie trying to find the duplicates across the two datasets

Comment: FYi it’s __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraper__, __scraped__) not scrap. ‘To scrap’ means to throw away like rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Sphinx/Manticore you can:

- take each of your products from dataset 1
- convert it into a query using a quorum operator with percentile and a ranking formula of your choice
- run the query against dataset 2
- find results
- take top K

There're some additional tricks that can help like:

- IDF boosting
- skipping stop-words
- use of atc-based ranking

The tricks and the concept of finding similar content in general are described in this interactive course - https://play.manticoresearch.com/mlt/